# Achieve functionality like snowball analyzer through normalizer on keyword type - ELASTICSEARCH 5.6

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have been trying to implement **snowball analyzer** like functionality on one of my doc fields which is of type **`keyword`**. Like, for example plurals should be treated exactly like their singulars so that results are same for both.

Initially, I struggled setting analyzer on my field just to discover that fields of type **`keyword`** cannot have **analyzers** but **normalizers**. So, I tried setting a **normalizer** for **`snowball`** on those fields but it seems like my normalizer is not allowing the **`snowball`** filter (may be normalizers don't support the snowball filter)

I can't change the type of the field. I want to achieve functionality like if my input text matches ***restaurants*** it should treat it same as **`restaurant`** and give the results so that I don't have to add restaurants as a keyword to that field.

Can we achieve this through normalizers? I have gone through the elastic documentations and various posts but got no clue. Below is how I tried setting normalizer with the response from my elastic server.

**PUT localhost:9200/db110/_settings**

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "normalizer": {
      "snowball_normalizer": {
        "filter": ["lowercase","snowball" ]
      }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "snow" : {
            "type" : "snowball",
            "language" : "English"
        }
    }
  }

}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Custom normalizer [snowball_normalizer] may not use filter [snowball]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Custom normalizer [snowball_normalizer] may not use filter [snowball]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't do that! Snowball is a stemmer and it is used for fulltext search - e.g. text datatype, because it is a token filter, that manipulates every single token. With keyword datatype you create a single token for all the content of the field. How stemmer could works for keyword field, according you? Use stemmer without tokens has no sense. Normalizer for keyword fields are only lowercase and asciifolding. Documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really helped. :)